# How to add Nuxt.js in an existing Express.js project?

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js

is there a way to export a nuxt.js project as an Express Middleware ?
also I want the Nuxt project files to be outside my Express project.

my scenario is that i want to add admin dashboard Front-End page , into my Back-End project.

Nuxt.render generates a Express Middleware but i don't know how to export the middleware.

what i'm looking for :

```
//backend/app.js
...

const nuxt_middleware = require('../front_project/nuxt_module');
express_app.use('/admin',await nuxt_middleware())
...
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, I had the same problem but I found the best way is to start new nuxt js project and then try to copy your codes,
you can go with [nuxt installation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation) to create new nuxt js app